# Finding the parallel sides of a trapezoid given all side lengths and height from base

Tags: geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

Suppose that we are given side lengths $a, b, c, d$ of a trapezoid. We know that two of them are parallel, and all values are different.

Moreover, we are given the height $h$ from the base (distance between two parallel lines).

The task is to find which sides are parallel.

I tried to form a triangle to use the triangle similarity, but I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Are sides of length $c$ and $a$ opposite to each other? If you look at Wikipedia article for trapezoid you'll see it answers your question for the two cases where one of sides is parallel and where two sides are parallel.

Comment: we do not know which sides are opposite

Comment: Do you know if exactly two sides are parallel?

Comment: yes, it is a scalene trapezoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the diagonal sides (I am not sure this is the standard way for calling them in English, so please edit this answer if needed) are $C$ and $D$ and the parallel sides are $A$ and $B$ with $A>B$,
$$ A = \sqrt{C^2-h^2}+\sqrt{D^2-h^2} + B \tag{1}$$
holds by the Pythagorean theorem.
 You may just check which permutation of $a,b,c,d$ fulfills this identity.

In $(1)$ I am actually also assuming that the angles on the major base are both acute.
 Some signs have to be changed in $(1)$ is this is not the case.

[image]

In this case, for instance, we have
$$ A = \color{red}{-}\sqrt{C^2-h^2}+\sqrt{D^2-h^2}+B.$$